# Override few php.ini settings on hosting server without changing rest of the settings

Tags: php, apache

I have just hosted my first website on hosting server, but I do not have access to the php.ini file of the server (as expected). So to change some settings like

```
display_errors = off
log_errors = on
file_upload = off
```

I created a `php.ini` file in the root directory with these only these 3 lines added, but it seems that this new `php.ini` files completely replaces the default `php.ini` file and I start getting errors like `class PDO not found` etc.

I just want to tweak few settings through this new `php.ini` files, leaving other settings intact. How can I do that? I don't want to do it through`ini_set` as it might require changes to many php files, I guess.

Comment: Have you tried with: [`.htaccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use an `.htaccess` file instead of directly modifying the `php.ini` file. Your requirement translates to `.htaccess` like this:

```
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag file_upload off
```

Comment: Will simply adding these lines in .htaccess will work? Is there any specific position where I should add these lines

Comment: Yes, the location of the `.htaccess` file should usually be inside the folder of the project whose settings you want to change...

Comment: Sorry, but I was not asking about the position of `.htaccess` file but I was asking for these 3 lines inside the .htaccess file. Is there any specific position required for these line, like at the top or before certain lines or I can play these lines anywhere inside the .htaccess file?

Comment: Placing it anywhere should be fine. Although you should try and place them at the top...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ini_set` in separate file and auto prepend it in .htaccess:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepend.php"
```

and in prepend.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);//etc, you can place here other configurations as well
```